# CakePHP Routing Slugs, detect Extension?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.6

In my 2.X app we're detecting which Tenant is using the system via a Slug in the URL, ie:

```
app/[tenant_slug]/[controller]/[action]
```

The issue however is that when the users browser requests for some static file our server doesn't have, such as:

```
app/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png
```

Cake takes 'apple-touch-icon-76x76' as the tenant_slug - so then our server has to determine that no, it doesn't have that slug and then throw back a Not Found error.

I have the following matching criteria on the route:

```
$validTenant = '[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+';
```

And I also have the following enabled:

```
CakePlugin::routes();
```

What is the correct way of handling this so the router knows that if a static resource is requested (ie: file ending in .js, .css, .png etc), it shouldn't use the file name as a slug? Or, should I have my code that looks up the tenant_slug (TenantAuthorizeComponent) handling the case where there is a file extension?

Answer (score 0):

I would handle this at the webserver level, if possible, do not even let php slow down your static files requests - for example for `nginx` I pass just php files into the interpreter using this statement in `mysite.vhost.conf`:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
   fastcgi_pass  php;
}
```